# Change of variable for integral formula...why?

Tags: calculus, random-variables

I'm reading a book on mathematical statistics and it states two properties of pdfs.

1) $f_X(x)\geq 0$
2) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(t)dt = 1$

My question is this. Why is the integration variable a t, not an x in the second equation?

Thanks

Comment: What's the difference anyway?

Comment: I think this prevents confusion with the $X$.

Comment: hhhmmm, so there doesn't seem to be some mathematical motivation behind it, just more readability motivation.

Comment: Ok, well put that as an answer then @Actoh, and I will accept it if that's ok with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only to close the question.

Absolutely no mathematical motivation. Probably to remove confusion with the $X$. But remember , that choice of notation, especially while writing a book, must be very careful, since one requires it to be consistently maintained throughout the book.

Therefore, this notation may by repeated through the book : as you read on, you will realize the role of t instead of x.

If notation is cluttered or variables are not chosen nicely, you could land in trouble. For example, I could write $f_X(t)$ as $\mathcal F_F(f)$ and there would be confusion as to what is what.

---

I should add that $t$ is varying from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. My guess is that $t$ usually varies over the reals in the book, as an integration variable. I have seen this in other books on probability as well.

Comment: This was an important answer to me as we all, at varying points, want to understand why something is done, not just accept that something is done. Thanks @Actoh. yep, in fact the author goes on to state, that if the pdf has these two properties then it is for a continuous random variabl.

Comment: In other words: nobody cares; the variables are dummies.

Comment: You are welcome! Having read some probability, I have also seen the same notation being stuck to by professors in class.